# Speeding up Python when using nested loops

Tags: python, loops, numpy, nested

This code, which contains 3 nested loops, in Matlab takes 30 sec to get run, instead, in Python more than 5 minutes. Any suggestion on how to make Python faster is highly appreciated! The code creates response spectra by using Newmark numerical solution. 
I am aware that vectorizing will resolve the challenge but I could not find space for implementing it.

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()
sig=np.loadtxt('LXR1N.txt')
t=sig[:,0]
ag=0.01*sig[:,1]
h=t[1]-t[0]
f=-ag
alfa=1/6; delta=0.5
alfa0=1/(alfa*h**2)
alfa1=delta/(alfa*h)
alfa2=1/(alfa*h)
alfa3=1/(2*alfa)-1
alfa4=delta/alfa-1
alfa5= h/2*(delta/alfa-2)
alfa6= h*(1-delta)
alfa7= delta*h;
D=np.array([0.01,0.04,0.06,0.1])
T=np.zeros(1198,float)
d=np.zeros([len(t)])
len(d)
v=np.zeros([len(t)])
a=np.zeros([len(t)])
fb=np.zeros([len(t)-1])
sd=np.empty((len(D),len(T)))
sa=np.empty((len(D),len(T)))
sv=np.empty((len(D),len(T)))
aex=np.empty((len(D),len(T)))
vex=np.empty((len(D),len(T)))
for i in range(0,len(T)):
        T[i]=0.015+0.005*i
i=None
s=-1
for q in D:
    s+=1
    for i in range(0,len(T)):
        omega=2*np.pi/T[i]
        c=2*q*omega
        k=omega**2
        kb=k+alfa0+alfa1*c
        d[0]=0
        v[0]=0
        a[0]=0
        for j in range(0,len(t)-1):
            fb[j]=f[j]+alfa0*d[j]+alfa2*v[j]+alfa3*a[j]+c*alfa1*d[j]+c*alfa4*v[j]+c*alfa5*a[j] 
            d[j+1]=fb[j]/kb
            a[j+1]=alfa0*d[j+1]-alfa0*d[j]-alfa2*v[j]-alfa3*a[j]
            v[j+1]=v[j]+alfa6*a[j]+alfa7*a[j+1]
        atot=a+ag
        atot1=-omega**2*d-2*q*omega*v
        sd[s,i]=max(abs(d))   
        sa[s,i]=omega**2*sd[s,i]
        sv[s,i]=omega*sd[s,i]
        aex[s,i]=max(abs(atot))
        vex[s,i]=max(abs(v))
del i
del j
plt.figure(1,figsize=(10, 4))
for i in range(sd.shape[0]):
    plt.plot(T,sd[i,:],label=str(D[i]*100)+"%")
    plt.xlabel("Period [s]")
    plt.ylabel("Sd [m]")
plt.xlim([0,6])
plt.ylim([0,0.6])
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('Sd.jpg')
plt.show()
plt.figure(2,figsize=(6, 3))
for j in range(sa.shape[0]):
    plt.plot(T,1/9.81*sa[j,:],label=str(D[j]*100)+"%")
    plt.xlabel("Period [s]")
    plt.ylabel("Sa [g]")
plt.xlim([0,6])
plt.ylim([0,2.5])
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('Sa.png')
plt.show()
stop = timeit.default_timer()
execution_time = stop - start

print("Program Executed in: ",execution_time, 'seconds')
```

Comment: Please provide some numerical data for sig, this way users may try to help you with a nice reproducible example. Also, did you just import numba @jit decorator without even using it?

Comment: Please add a full working example. This includes a function with well defined input and outputs (one for the calculation one for plotting) @Yacola There are a few things in the code which Numba can't cope with. eg. v=np.zeros([len(t)])

Comment: I found it as a recommendation and actually just by importing it the running time reduced by 20 some seconds.

Comment: Here is the txt file:(https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1xz7exn4bsgvum/LXR1N.txt?dl=0)

Comment: MATLAB implements jit compiling that lets you use iteration without much of a time penalty.  `numpy` is like older MATLAB versions that required us to think in terms of whole-array operations, what are commonly called `vectorized`.  But with just a casual read it is hard to tell how much of your code is inherently serial in nature (must do one loop after the other), and what can be done in a 'parallel' (i.e. performed in compiled, whole-array methods).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried profiling? It should be able to tell you where the time cost is. Try using the cProfile module and then visualize with snakeViz. Once you have profiled your code you can look to optimize certain sections depending if its IO bound or CPU bound.

1 example could be replacing for loops with iterators where possible. I.e.

```
for i in range(0,len(T)):
        T[i]=0.015+0.005*i
```

to

```
T = [0.015+0.005*i for i in range(len(T))]
```

Timing using time.time() for len(T) = 10000, on my PC the second code runs 0.0009 seconds faster.

You might also want to have a look at multi threading or multiprocessing solutions. Generally this would make the code much more complex, but would allow python to use more of your processing power available. Use multithreading if you're IO bound and multiprocessing if you're CPU bound.

Although without profiling and/or knowing the size of the dataset its pretty hard to suggest any changes that would guarantee improved performance.

PS. do check out the docs on Python multiprocessing and threading.

> https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: Yes, I know where the delay comes from. It comes from the third loop as it is the longest one.

Comment: Are you sure? It may seem long because you are going len(D)*i*j iterations into that loop. Is there anything there that can be optimized? You could try mapping with lambda functions instead of just using raw array indexing and math operators? I think it might be faster that way although I am no expert. Also I think numpy should provide some means to perform the algorithm faster through their own API....hmmm

Answer (score 0):

### Just compile it

With minor changes of the code that should't be used in pure Python code either, like `np.zeros([len(t)])` the part of your function which only uses Numpy funcs is easy to compile using Numba.

hpaulj already explained in the comments that the performance benefit from Matlab in this case is related to jit-compilation. Whith some limitations (only most of Numpy functions supported) this is easy to do in Python also.

**Implementation**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(error_model="numpy")
def func_nb(sig):
    t=sig[:,0]
    ag=0.01*sig[:,1]
    h=t[1]-t[0]
    f=-ag
    alfa=1/6; delta=0.5
    alfa0=1/(alfa*h**2)
    alfa1=delta/(alfa*h)
    alfa2=1/(alfa*h)
    alfa3=1/(2*alfa)-1
    alfa4=delta/alfa-1
    alfa5= h/2*(delta/alfa-2)
    alfa6= h*(1-delta)
    alfa7= delta*h
    D=np.array([0.01,0.04,0.06,0.1])
    T=np.zeros(1198)
    d=np.zeros(len(t))
    v=np.zeros(len(t))
    a=np.zeros(len(t))
    fb=np.zeros((len(t)-1))
    sd=np.empty((len(D),len(T)))
    sa=np.empty((len(D),len(T)))
    sv=np.empty((len(D),len(T)))
    aex=np.empty((len(D),len(T)))
    vex=np.empty((len(D),len(T)))
    for i in range(0,len(T)):
        T[i]=0.015+0.005*i

    for s in range(D.shape[0]):
        q=D[s]
        for i in range(0,len(T)):
            omega=2*np.pi/T[i]
            c=2*q*omega
            k=omega**2
            kb=k+alfa0+alfa1*c
            d[0]=0
            v[0]=0
            a[0]=0
            for j in range(0,len(t)-1):
                fb[j]=f[j]+alfa0*d[j]+alfa2*v[j]+alfa3*a[j]+c*alfa1*d[j]+c*alfa4*v[j]+c*alfa5*a[j] 
                d[j+1]=fb[j]/kb
                a[j+1]=alfa0*d[j+1]-alfa0*d[j]-alfa2*v[j]-alfa3*a[j]
                v[j+1]=v[j]+alfa6*a[j]+alfa7*a[j+1]
            atot=a+ag
            atot1=-omega**2*d-2*q*omega*v
            sd[s,i]=np.max(np.abs(d))   
            sa[s,i]=omega**2*sd[s,i]
            sv[s,i]=omega*sd[s,i]
            aex[s,i]=np.max(np.abs(atot))
            vex[s,i]=np.max(np.abs(v))
    return sd,sa,sv,aex,vex
```

**Timings**

```
sig=np.loadtxt("LXR1N.txt")
%timeit sd,sa,sv,aex,vex=func(sig)
#1.33 s ± 4.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#I simply don't want to wait for multiple runs
import time
t1=time.time()
sd,sa,sv,aex,vex=orig()
print(time.time()-t1)
#229.00757384300232
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, this resolved the issue. But I have another question regarding:@nb.njit(error_model="numpy"). I put this command on my first code (the one presented in the first comment) and actually it did not work, in the sense that everything below @nb.njit(error_model="numpy") was not recognized as valid syntax. Is this command used only before functions? The x symbol will appear right in the first line below it.

Comment: @E V You have to put this command directly above a function, or you can compile a function also with `my_func_nb=nb.njit(myfunc)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. It is clear now. But it can be any other solution in case I do not want to work with functions?

Comment: @EV No, (not any that I know), but it would be anyway highly recommendable to structure your code within functions.